# How can I get the wallet distribution of a token?

Tags: nft, native-assets

I'd like to determine the number of wallet holders for (example)

1. Lobster holders
2. ClayNation owners

How can I query this with a full node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need db-sync to get that sort of data. https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync

You can use existing solutions like Koios (https://api.koios.rest/#overview).

Example for Lobster token:

```
curl -X GET "https://api.koios.rest/api/v0/asset_txs?_asset_policy=8654e8b350e298c80d2451beb5ed80fc9eee9f38ce6b039fb8706bc3&_asset_name=4c4f4253544552"
```

Response:

```
[
  {
    "policy_id": "8654e8b350e298c80d2451beb5ed80fc9eee9f38ce6b039fb8706bc3",
    "asset_name": "4c4f4253544552",
    "total_transactions": 340660,
    "staked_wallets": 2433,
    "unstaked_addresses": 9
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know about koios.